# Why is my Mongoose controller not getting called?

Tags: angular, express, mongoose

I am in the midst of creating an API in Mongoose and Express, and already have many routes set up that are working correctly.  I'm trying to create a route that searches for a model called Subassembly by its name and returns the object id.  My problem is that I cannot seem to get the controller to fire and I don't know why or what I'm doing wrong.

I've console logged out all of my function calls in my Angular front end and everything seems to be correct.

Subscribing to Angular service call:

```
  addSubassembly () {
    const localSubassembly: object = this._subAssemblyService.getSubassemblyByName(formValue);
  }
```

My Angular service call:

```
  public getSubassemblyByName (name: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get<Subassembly>(`${this.subassemblyUrl}name`, { 
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      observe: 'response',
      params: {'subassemblyName': name }
    });
  }
```

Gets passed to my Express index (the second get is called, getByName):

```
router.get('/subassembly', subassembly.get);
router.get('/subassembly/name', subassembly.getByName);
router.get('/subassembly/:id', subassembly.getById);
router.post('/subassembly', subassembly.create);
router.put('/subassembly/:id', subassembly.modify);
router.delete('/subassembly/:id', subassembly.remove);
```

Which calls the controller:

```
/* jslint node: true, nomen: true */
'use strict';

const Subassembly = require('../../models/subassembly.js');

const getByName = function (req, res) {
    Subassembly.find(req.body).then(function (doc) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send(doc);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    })
};

module.exports = getByName;
```

It's all pretty boilerplate stuff, so I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Does anyone else have any suggestions about what I might be missing?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to `getSubassemblyByName`?

Comment: I just added the code snippet to show where I called getSubassemblyByName().  I'm calling that in my Angualr component ts file as a click event on a button.

Comment: Calling the function is not the same as subscribing to it. Without subscribe, nothing will happen. https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing

Comment: You're correct, I blanked and missed that one.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need subscribe the call if you call it in component ts

```
_service.getSubassemblyByName().subscribe(() => {
       // access the name here
});
```

Comment: the best practice is try not to use subscribe as possible. you will find it not convinent, as sometimes you will have to manually call changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() in order to  refresh the page with new value. Try to use `async` pipe if possible is a better approach.